# Multiple transactions on a single InnoDB table possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions

This is a question regarding SQL, but the aim is to create a php script.

**CONTEXT**

Let say I have one database containing 2 tables (set on InnoDB engine) :

- users
- cart

Now 2 users access my application (in php), and both launch a web page that is doing the following algorithm :

1. Open the connection
2. Open a transaction
3. Insert a new line in the table user
4. Commit the transaction

**QUESTION**

Can SQL handle 2 transactions on the same table ?

**PhP Code (for the record)**

```
$host = 'localhost';
$database = 'user';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$encode = 'utf8';
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database;charset=$encode";
$pdo = null;

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $query = "INSERT INTO user (name, city) VALUES ('test', 'Paris')";
    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    if( $pdo->inTransaction() ) {
        // Can I still launch the query ?
    }
    else {
        // Or should I stop here ?
    }

    if( $pdo->query( $query ) ) {
        $pdo->commit();
    }
    else {
        $pdo->rollBack();
    }   
}
catch( PDOException $e ) {
    print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
}
```

Comment: Yes, SQL can handle multiple transactions at the same time. Think about it.. This must be happening every minute on Google, Twitter, Facebook etc. *Having said that, what really is your question?*

Comment: So the transaction does not "lock" the table, and there can be 2 or more transaction at the exact same time inserting data, is that right ?

Comment: @Zeratops that completely depends on your table type, MyISAM, MEMORY and MERGE all use table level blocking

Comment: @MarkTwigg thank your for this information. What about InnoDB ? I am currenlty using this type of table.

Comment: From mysql docs: "Transactions are protected (isolated) from each other while they are in progress; they cannot interfere with each other or see each other's uncommitted data. This isolation is achieved through the locking mechanism." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_acid

Comment: @Zeratops InnoDB uses row level blocking

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data only as arguments on `execute` to avoid potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for advice on how to avoid problem like this.

Comment: If you're doing a single insert there's no reason for a transaction. That's only useful if you have a second query that conditionally depends on the first, or which should not be done in isolation.

Comment: Thank you @tadman, actually I am on prepared statement but for this example I wanted to keep this as clear as possible.

Comment: @tadman this code isn't open to SQL injection because hes hard coded the inputs obviously to test the theory and is not accepting any user input

Comment: @MarkTwigg I always flag because assuming is more dangerous than warning.

Comment: @tadman there are no assumptions, the values are hardcoded in the query and at no point does he accept user input, I can't see where you have decided SQL injection is possible here, no input = not possible.

Comment: @MarkTwigg If prepared statements aren't used here then there's a strong chance they're not used anywhere. This is the whole point of an advisory warning. It's also for anyone who might see this code in the future and be tempted to use it as-is or by substituting variables.

Comment: @Zeratops if your table is InnoDB then there is no table locking from MySql

Comment: @MarkTwigg alright, good to hear. Thank you all for your information. I might conclude that on InnoDB, transactions are not interfering each other which in my scenario is quite safe to use without checking for `PDO::inTransaction()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, you can perform multiple queries while in a transaction. This is actually the point of using transactions.

[In PDO, from the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php), as long as you have started a transaction by calling `PDO::beginTransaction()`, you may perform multiple queries, and the changes are not seen by anyone else until you are finished (i.e. by calling `PDO::commit()`).

> You're not limited to making updates in a transaction; you can also issue complex queries to extract data, and possibly use that information to build up more updates and queries; while the transaction is active, you are guaranteed that no one else can make changes while you are in the middle of your work. For further reading on transactions, refer to the documentation provided by your database server.

Using InnoDB engine in MySQL, specifically, you have row-level granularity, which means only rows are locked, not the entire table like in (older) MyISAM engine.

Comment: The comparison with MyISAM helps to understand the one-row level lock.

Answer (score 1):

You can have any number of transactions open in MySQL if you're using the InnoDB engine. There's a small cost for each open transaction that is usually a marginal issue unless you're dealing with a table that's being swamped with write activity. As the number of transactions open grows the harder it is for MySQL to maintain the various incomplete versions.

If you want to know more about how MySQL handles transactions there's a [huge section on it in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html) where they discuss the implications of MVCC (Multi-Version Concurrency Control).

Transactions are only really relevant if you have more than one operation you're looking to make *atomic*, that is either all of the queries succeed or they all fail. In your example here you have a single statement, which is by definition atomic. Wrapping it in a transaction block introduces more overhead that doesn't really give you anything you didn't already have.

Comment: You totally right, I would save this solution in case I am making several inserts within my script but in my particular scenario (one insert at a time) transactions reveal not useful. Thank you !

Comment: If you've got several things you need to do and ensure they happen as a unit then transactions are essential. If you call `beginTransaction()` and you don't get an error, you're free to continue, there's no reason to check if you're actually in a transaction at that point.